# How to paste inputs in console window while debugging with Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm making a console application receiving inputs from console window. If I use Eclipse for IDE, I can paste inputs to console window. But I can't paste inputs to console window if I use Visual C++ for IDE. Is there any way to paste inputs in console window made by Visual C++?

Comment: You mean programmatically or manually? You may need to use pipes for stdout for former, and you may use right-click (on title bar), and using Edit menu.

Answer (score 14):

Click on the icon of console window
Press Edit -> Paste

[image]